# Can we connect to Azure VM remotely which is different Virtual Network

Tags: powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network

I have 2 Azure VMs , say `VM1` and `VM2`. I have logged into `VM1` through RDP. Now my requirement is to connect to `VM2` from `VM1` through powershell and run some commands remotely.

When I run the below command :

```
$UserName = "<IP>\username"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password@123" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName, $Password)
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName <IP> -Credential $psCred
```

It is giving the following error :

New-PSSession : [] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

I have tried all the solutions which I found on internet, but none solved my problem.

The VirtualNetwork/Subnet of both the VMs is different and both of them do no have public IP and DNS name(which is a business requirement and cannot be changed) . So I'm using Private IP to login.Location of both the VMs is also different.

Is there a possibility that this might be the reason?

Comment: just confirm that. The two VMs are in different subnet or vnet?

Comment: @NancyXiong-MSFT Different VNET as well as different subnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should confirm that the two different virtual network connection is working by Network Peering on the virtual network panel. This is [Demo](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureedu/2018/04/24/how-to-setup-global-vnet-peering-in-azure/).

Then, you need to open the ports 5985 in the inbound rule of NSG associated with that subnet. Also, temporarily turn off the firewall locally to run the following scripts. Alternatively, you can use below command to add an incoming rule to allow traffic on port 5985:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -Name "winrm_http" -DisplayName "winrm_http" -Enabled True -Profile Any -Action Allow -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 5985 -Protocol TCP
```

**On Server**

Run the `winrm quickconfig` command in Command Prompt to analyzes and configures the WinRM service. Run `Enable-PSRemoting -Force` to enable the machine is configured for WinRM remote management. You also can check the port 5985 is listening by running `netstat -a`.

[image]

**On Client**

Run the `winrm quickconfig` command in Command Prompt to configure the WinRM service. Add the IP address of the remote machine to trusted hosts in the client of remote PS. `Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value 172.18.20.4`

Then run your commands as the screenshot.

[image]

Ref: [Enable PowerShell Remoting](https://4sysops.com/archives/enable-powershell-remoting/)

Comment: If this helps, you can accept it, or let me know if you need more info in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was following the steps given in the link above for Global VNet peering. At the 5th step, when I did a ping to one machine from another, it saying Request Timed out.

Comment: Can you try to rdp to vm2 from vm1 with its private ip? Also, check if you enable peering each other in both of two vNets.

Comment: No , I'm not able to do RDP from one VM to another.  Yes , I have enabled peering in both the Vnets

Comment: What is the peering status, it should be connected. And, turn off the firewall locally on the VM, still the same error?

Comment: Yes, the peering status in both the VNets is connected. I do not have permissions to turn off the firewall in any of the machines. It is a long procedure in our company to do the same. Any other way I can check?

Comment: You can check if the rdp port allows in the NSG rules of two subnets. If the vnet peering success, you can rdp with its private ip unless the local firewall blocking. Also, check if VM is running normally.

Comment: Should I disable to firewall in VM1 or VM2 , if I'm trying to connect from VM1 to VM2. Also I have seen in Control Panel, we have Private Profile, Domain profile and Public Profile. For all of them the firewall is On. Which one should I turn off?

Comment: Yes, you can turn off the private profile for a workgroup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180311/discussion-between-crazycoder-and-nancy-xiong-msft).

Comment: Looks like its just the firewall issue. Thanks a lot for helping me out.